# Convert a SVG path to coordinates (for plotting in Excel)

Tags: svg, web-scraping

I'm trying to fetch a graph from a website, which is given as an SVG path like below.

```
M52.05,268.53L53.38,280.69L54.72,272.1L56.05,280.14L57.38,283.32L58.72,277.49L60.05,277.17L61.38,277.55L62.72,270.35L64.05,270.32L65.38,273.73L66.71,282.57L68.04,279.56L69.38,275.8L70.71,281.05L72.04,269.55L73.38,277.33L74.71,270.05L76.04,276.57L77.37,262.82L78.71,258.66L80.04,251.08L81.37,254.97L82.71,264.37L84.04,258.64L86.7,266.8L88.04,268.83L90.7,275.66L92.03,272.78L93.37,280.58L94.7,278.81L96.03,279.36L97.36,274.79L98.7,274.71L100.03,286.08L101.36,277.78L102.69,283.66L104.03,267.74L105.36,266.36L106.69,285.91L108.03,260.23L109.36,261.83L110.69,262.16L112.03,272.07L113.36,265.75L114.69,278.15L116.03,276.24L117.36,270.12L118.69,273.03L120.02,267.83L121.35,257.44L122.69,270.04L124.02,266.42L125.36,277.05L126.69,266.55L128.02,275.73L129.35,279.39L132.02,264.17L133.35,274.52L134.68,275.29L136.02,257.54L137.39,244.81L138.68,269.88L141.35,268.89L142.68,275.54L144.01,280.05L145.34,280.13L146.68,271.56L148.01,273.36L150.67,258.78L152.01,260.41L153.34,267.66L154.67,255.66L156.01,266.39L157.34,264.04L158.67,268.19L160,258.36L161.33,266.4L162.67,260.21L164,264.19L165.33,273.71L166.67,264.44L168,269.59L169.34,250.43L170.67,248.2L172,266.51L173.33,261.71L174.66,258.73L176,264.43L177.33,260.88L178.66,262.6L181.33,274.1L182.66,261.1L183.99,264.98L185.32,254.35L186.66,249.54L187.99,251.99L189.32,256.87L190.65,255.7L191.99,257.49L193.32,256.54L194.65,272.87L195.98,276.22L198.65,259.59L199.98,260.07L201.32,261.04L202.65,252.77L203.98,250.02L205.32,252.85L207.98,239.4L209.31,255.92L210.64,265.16L211.98,264.67L213.31,261.67L214.64,226.54L217.31,260.25L218.64,257.77L219.98,255.26L221.31,268.24L222.64,260.15L223.97,261.69L225.3,257.85L226.64,269.23L229.3,258.34L230.64,256.55L231.97,263.52L233.3,253.27L234.64,251.35L235.97,250.94L237.3,252.36L238.63,258.37L239.96,261.79L241.3,251.57L242.63,255.67L243.96,255.43L245.3,261.29L246.63,261.86L247.96,258.21L249.3,265.39L250.63,265.65L251.96,258.27L253.29,255.03L254.62,254.05L255.96,260.26L257.29,259.69L258.62,259.72L259.96,278.66L261.29,270.59L262.62,280.02L265.29,272.01L266.62,271.08L267.95,264.53L269.28,266.57L270.62,274.61L271.95,275.19L273.28,270.94L274.61,271.46L275.95,263.93L277.28,262.9L278.61,271.91L279.95,275.83L281.28,260.88L282.61,257.28L283.95,259.69L285.28,252.79L286.61,257.91L287.94,255.45L289.28,257.27L290.61,262.71L291.94,261.38L293.27,263.7L294.61,258.16L295.94,262.44L299.94,268.17L301.27,261.69L302.6,252.19L303.94,256.83L305.27,271.46L306.6,263.58L307.93,258.92L309.27,261.28L310.6,261.64L311.93,267.96L313.27,264L314.6,257.34L315.93,251.74L317.26,253.81L318.6,254.84L319.93,257.76L322.59,252.37L323.93,257.18L326.59,259.07L327.93,263.67L329.26,263.74L330.59,269.6L331.92,259L333.26,264.45L334.59,258.58L335.92,261L338.58,267.64L339.92,262.65L341.25,265.2L342.58,274.62L345.25,258.32L346.58,262.76L347.91,268.79L349.25,271.16L350.58,265.1L351.92,268.38L354.58,257.99L355.91,262.22L357.24,267.5L358.58,266.55L362.57,256.62L363.91,259.47L365.24,270.87L366.57,266.43L367.9,258.91L369.24,264.34L370.57,255.82L371.9,265.81L374.57,256.23L375.9,259.58L378.57,265.52L379.9,257.53L381.23,262.4L382.56,260.59L383.9,267.87L385.23,258.04L386.56,257L387.9,250.56L389.23,249.44L390.56,254.43L391.9,256.03L393.23,247.81L394.56,251.9L395.91,246.89L397.23,257.02L398.56,254.01L399.89,259.4L401.22,258.55L402.56,258.48L403.89,246.98L405.22,254.3L406.55,255.47L409.22,261.03L410.55,260.87L411.89,258.84L413.22,254.88L414.55,256.87L415.88,266.74L417.21,261.12L418.55,266.2L422.55,252.79L423.88,258.84L425.21,251.53L426.55,262.21L427.88,250.22L429.21,249.73L430.54,259.1L431.87,257.73L433.21,253.59L434.54,256.05L435.87,257.79L437.21,265.3L438.54,254.52L439.87,251.83L441.21,266.96L442.54,255.09L443.87,252.83L445.2,260.47L449.2,267.99L450.54,256.36L451.87,258.9L453.2,253.93L454.53,252.98L455.87,256.63L457.2,254.29L458.53,248.02L459.86,254.66L461.2,246.99L462.53,260.29L463.86,262.09L466.53,262.22L467.86,265.37L469.19,264.12L470.53,254.29L471.86,257.62L473.19,252.28L474.52,260.39L475.85,259.09L477.19,262.82L478.52,257.04L479.85,264.03L481.19,265.06L482.52,257.68L483.85,261.61L485.18,266.75L486.52,263.09L487.85,260.44L489.18,269.59L490.51,268.49L491.85,260.4L493.18,249.61L494.51,259.5L495.84,254.22L497.18,265.52L498.51,254.8L499.84,255.31L501.18,251.11L502.51,263.44L503.84,263.32L505.17,264.2L506.51,253.24L507.84,260.16L509.17,260.92L510.51,257.37L511.84,256.86L513.17,253.98L515.84,233.52L517.17,232.08L518.5,261.96L519.83,263.86L521.17,260.09L522.5,261.5L523.83,260.41L525.17,261.62L526.5,270.08L527.83,271.93L529.16,275.77L530.5,274.5L531.83,277.53L533.16,271.99L535.83,257.92L537.16,254.89L538.5,247.63L539.83,249.91L541.16,228.12L542.49,257.41L543.83,261.42L545.16,258.89L546.49,265.69L547.83,249.76L549.16,259.4L550.49,248.67L551.82,268.04L553.16,264.7L554.49,263.02L555.82,231.01L557.15,231.1L558.49,253.62L559.82,254.13L561.15,263.82L562.49,252.49L563.82,255.73L565.15,252.18L566.48,265.08L567.81,271.85L569.15,264.39L570.48,261.76L571.81,256.65L573.15,239.62L574.48,245.26L575.82,242.24L577.15,244.61L578.48,246.22L579.81,254.24L581.23,205.11L582.57,215.36L585.42,254.66L586.5,246.15L587.81,263.1L589.15,252.4L590.47,260.68L591.8,256.79L593.14,250.7L594.47,256.49L595.82,260.78L597.17,253.54L598.47,263.49L599.8,264.03L601.13,266.64L602.47,264.44L603.8,257.91L605.13,275.02L606.46,263.31L607.79,259.09L609.13,252.69L610.46,257.41L611.79,257.31L613.13,252.88L614.46,245.23L615.79,248.99L617.12,250.38L618.46,247.07L619.79,247.03L621.12,245.86L622.45,244.38L623.79,244.58L625.12,241.15L626.45,255.75L627.79,249.67L629.12,253.22L631.78,203.97L633.12,208.88L634.45,246.24L635.78,242.61L638.45,258.65L639.78,252L641.11,244.53L642.44,263.64L643.78,253.43L645.11,263.5L646.44,261.04L647.78,250.89L649.11,248.22L650.44,237.25L651.78,225.53L653.11,247.45L654.44,259.23L655.77,259.78L657.1,256.92L658.44,251.74L659.77,251.79L661.1,252.96L662.44,246.32L663.77,250.83L665.1,249.7L666.43,240.93L667.77,252L669.1,242.18L670.43,242.72L671.77,234.95L673.1,238.67L674.43,212.5L675.76,177.42L677.1,203.01L679.76,254.43L681.09,252.02L682.43,247.73L683.76,249.34L685.09,249.66L686.42,246.36L687.76,245.9L689.09,248.62L690.42,240.83L691.76,242.04L694.42,245.73L695.75,249.46L698.42,247.61L699.75,251.45L701.08,249.55L702.42,244.28L705.08,238.07L706.42,244.05L707.75,245.94L709.08,251.14L711.75,249.86L713.08,244.29L715.74,235.94L717.08,243.87L718.41,243.36L719.74,240.57L721.07,243.06L722.41,240.51L726.41,252.15L727.74,252.17L729.07,258.39L730.4,258.43L731.73,269.08L733.07,266.21L734.4,263.15L735.73,265.6L737.07,254.11L738.4,252.83L739.73,249.22L741.07,248.97L742.4,256.57L743.73,248.75L745.06,258.85L746.39,251.72L747.73,251.37L749.06,246.11L750.39,247.05L751.73,245.66L753.06,249.62L754.39,243.2L755.73,243.28L757.06,251.58L758.39,251.32L759.72,252.83L762.39,242.9L763.72,243.11L765.05,249.28L766.39,247.62L767.72,261.46L769.05,266.73L770.38,257.1L771.72,253.58L773.05,250.84L774.38,252.42L777.05,233.23L778.38,248.58L779.71,241.1L781.05,239.7L782.38,240.5L783.71,239.31L785.04,240.87L786.38,233.32L787.71,234.25L789.04,244.46L791.71,265.71L793.04,252.69L795.7,267.54L797.04,255.11L798.37,264.11L799.7,256.23L801.04,261.84L802.37,257.29L803.7,269.91L805.04,262.83L806.37,254.32L807.7,268.28L809.03,268.63L810.37,257.96L811.7,257.47L813.03,272.34L814.36,271.33L815.7,278.05L817.03,259.27L818.36,267.55L819.7,261.21L821.03,260.6L822.36,261.54L823.69,255.38L825.03,266.93L826.37,258.6L829.02,231.63L830.36,233.46L833.02,239.62L834.36,233.14L837.02,247.07L838.36,231.34L841.02,252.61L842.35,239.03L843.69,239.37L845.02,246.17L846.35,246.88L847.68,264.9L849.02,249.75L850.35,255.24L851.68,254.75L853.02,271.72L854.35,263.55L855.69,272.45L858.35,236.61L859.68,242.22L861.02,265.89L862.34,238.68L863.68,227.2L865.01,256.49L866.34,256.03L867.68,264.11L869.01,263.47L870.36,269.69L871.68,272.12L873,264.62L874.34,267.85L875.67,261.26L878.33,269L879.67,263.24L881,268.44L882.33,269.51L883.67,268.61L885,257.23L886.33,274.58L887.66,267.96L889,271.45L890.33,257.48L891.66,264.46L892.99,257.6L894.33,254.64L895.66,262.24L896.99,263.55L898.33,259.29L899.66,260.22L900.99,262.61L902.32,264.46L903.66,268.13L906.32,274.03L907.65,272.56L908.99,268.96L910.32,267.99L911.65,271.57L912.98,265.67L914.32,260.14L915.65,277.12L916.98,279.31L918.32,266.28L919.65,273.53L920.98,271.51L923.65,264.73L924.98,272.69L926.31,269.45L927.65,272.54L928.98,267.68L930.31,267.14L931.64,274.96L932.98,274.97L934.31,274.77L935.64,266.05L936.97,280.2L938.31,267.39L939.64,263.81L940.97,267.38L942.3,268.83L943.64,264.78L944.97,265.73L946.3,272.51L947.63,262.57L948.97,265.6L950.3,271.09L951.63,260.65L952.96,271.19L954.3,264.79L955.63,256L956.96,268.65L958.3,267.78L959.63,268.68L960.96,275.73L962.29,265.12L963.63,268.1L964.96,275.87L966.29,272.34L967.63,265.22L968.96,269.12L970.29,268.75L971.62,267.67L972.96,269.22L974.29,265.36L975.62,271.94L976.96,261.16L978.29,276.02L980.95,263.23L982.29,268.42L983.62,260.55L984.95,260.17L987.62,267.85L988.95,268.89
```

I want to convert this into X,Y coordinates (to plot into Excel). How can I do this in the simplest way (preferably with Javascript)?

Comment: Welcome! Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how you tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us exactly what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. Read [How to Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Be sure to take the tour and read this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is surprisingly easy, given your dataset. `M` is the directive to Move to the following coordinates, `L` draws a Line from the prior spot, to the following spot. So we can replace all `M`s and `L`s with spaces, and split the string into coords.

Clean out the SVG directives, split it on the spaces, and then split those on the comma to get an array of arrays that have an X/Y coordinates.

Note: `replaceAll` has poor support on older browsers.

```
svgPath.replaceAll("M", " ").replaceAll("L"," ").split(" ").map(x => x.split(","))
```

Comment: This works as intended. Thank you very much. Afterwards, I found out that you can also manipulate the string from within Excel itself with a similar concept.

Comment: is there a method for general path strings?